# Re-set user.IsPortalEnabled field?

Tags: apex, customer-portal

**I can't figure out how to set IsPortalEnabled to true, once it has been set to false.** Not a critical issue, just trying to increase my knowledge and understanding of the platform.

I was playing around on my dev org and ran:

```
list<user> lst = new list<user>();
for(user u :[SELECT id, name , IsPortalEnabled, isActive FROM User where IsPortalEnabled=true]){
   u.Isportalenabled=false; 
   lst.add(u);
}
update lst;
```

which disabled my portal user and set him to active, trying to reactivate the user in through the gui I got "Error: Cannot activate a disabled portal user" which is understandable.

Trying to reverse my actions, I ran:

```
list<user> lst = new list<user>();

for(user u :[SELECT id, name , IsPortalEnabled, isActive FROM User where id = '005d0000001DXMx']){
    u.Isportalenabled=true;
    lst.add(u);
}
update lst;
```

which gave an dml exception

> EXCEPTION: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 005d0000001DXMxAAO; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Cannot enable a disabled portal user: [IsPortalEnabled]
>   STACKTRACE: AnonymousBlock: line 7, column 1

Trying to re-enable the portal user through the button on the contact detail page, just ended up in creating a new user.

**Anyone who can shed some light on this, is it totally not possible to reverse setting IsPortalEnabled to false ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you cannot re-enable that exact user record once it is disabled (which is what the error message states...sort of).  Take a look at http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customer_portal_disable_users.htm.

Comment: ah darn, I didn't find that when looking in the documentation.